# Initial notification is null on iOS when app launched via a notification action react-native push-notification-ios

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-native-push-notification

https://github.com/react-native-push-notification/ios#getinitialnotification is used to get the initial notification to know if the app is launched by a notification. The notification is null if the app is launched via a notification action. It works fine if I tap on a notification to launch the app. But if I long-press the notification to view the notification actions and tap on one of the notification actions to launch the app, then then `getInitialNotification` method returns null and the code assumes that the app was not started via a notification.

How can I get this to work?